# Add WFS layer to Openlayers2 map

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, wfs, request

(UPDATE QUESTION)

I have a problem with WFS request, mine is as follows:

```
var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS",{                      
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({                        
        version: "1.1.0",                                
        url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs", 
        featureNS : "http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite",
        // field Namespace URI in Edit Workspace
        geometryName: "geom",
        // property of Geometry type in Edit Layer
        featureType: "InfoGeometric",
        // filed Name in Edit LayerLayer Name   
        featurePrefix: 'cite'
        // field name in Edit Workspace
    }),
});
```

In GeoServer I can see geometric features in preview. If I go on

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?
    version=1.1.0&
    typename=cite:InfoGeometric
```

and

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/GetFeature?
    version=1.1.0&
    typename=cite:InfoGeometric
```

I see the columns table and data table.

After request on my map there is "WFS" layer but no features. I think that the request is submitted correctly (from my HTML page, through the proxy to `localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs`, code.  `200 OK`), but the response is not direct to my map in fact if I see it in firebug I see the proxy.cgi file while I aspect my features!!!!! Can anybody give me an advise?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The very first step would be using a tool like Firebug to see the WFS requests your application is creating and check if it is receiving features from the WFS server as response.

Comment: two questions for you:1) Where is your html page currently? It has to be in a webserver to work. In addition, it needs a proxy to be working, if it is not in the same webserver as Geoserver. 2) Do you have any other layer in your map? Is that being displayed?

Comment: I am not sure how you have both Geoserver & another webserver running on the same port. It might be that wfs services might not be visible. what happens when you try to open the following link: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?typename=cite%3AInfoGeometric&Request=getcapabilities

Comment: What web server are you using? Do you know that the proxy cgi script is actually being executed? The fact that your response contains the cgi script would suggest that it is not being executed!

Comment: CHenderson, thanks for your reply. I read that in tomcat 6 must uncomment tag <servlet> and <servlet-mapping> in web.xml and in context.xml add the attribute provileged = true to tag Content (<Context privileged="true">). Again in response have proxy.cgi file. My application url is http://localhost:8081/ProofConsSpazial/index.html, if i go on http://localhost:8081/ProofConsSpazial/proxy.cgi i see my proxy.cgi file while i aspect openlayers.org. It is clear that i made a mistake, problem is where and why.